# Sum of 2 columns if row exists in Table 2 - SQL

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE #Details
(
SName       VARCHAR(20),
PName       VARCHAR(20),
SoldCount   INT,
Value       INT
)

CREATE TABLE #DetailsException
(
ExSName     VARCHAR(20),
ExPName     VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO #Details(SName, PName, SoldCount,Value) VALUES ('Store 1', 'Product 1', 10,400)
INSERT INTO #Details(SName, PName, SoldCount,Value) VALUES ('Store 1', 'Product 3', 3,500)
INSERT INTO #Details(SName, PName, SoldCount,Value) VALUES ('Store 2', 'Product 1', 8,30)
INSERT INTO #Details(SName, PName, SoldCount,Value) VALUES ('Store 2', 'Product 2', 10,25)
INSERT INTO #Details(SName, PName, SoldCount,Value) VALUES ('Store 2', 'Product 2', 23,120)
INSERT INTO #Details(SName, PName, SoldCount,Value) VALUES ('Store 4', 'Product 1', 23,50)
INSERT INTO #Details(SName, PName, SoldCount,Value) VALUES ('Store 4', 'Product 3', 10,50)
INSERT INTO #Details(SName, PName, SoldCount,Value) VALUES ('Store 4', 'Product 5', 7,200)
INSERT INTO #Details(SName, PName, SoldCount,Value) VALUES ('Store 5', 'Product 1', 10,100)
INSERT INTO #Details(SName, PName, SoldCount,Value) VALUES ('Store 5', 'Product 1', 24,240)

INSERT INTO #DetailsException(ExSName, ExPName) VALUES ('Store 2', 'Product 2')
INSERT INTO #DetailsException(ExSName, ExPName) VALUES ('Store 4', 'Product 5')

SELECT SName, PName, **CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #DetailsException WHERE ExSName = SName AND ExPName = PNAme ) THEN 0 ELSE SUM(SoldCount) END AS SoldCount**, SUM(Value) AS Value
FROM #Details
GROUP BY SNAME, PNAME
ORDER BY SNAME, PNAME
```

The result set is correct. Although I want to know if there any other optimized way of writing it in SQL. Since both the tables will grow extremely large in size.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would be more inclined to write this as a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT d.SName, d.PName, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN de.ExSname IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE SoldCount END) AS SoldCount,
       SUM(Value) AS Value
FROM #Details d LEFT JOIN
     #DetailsException de
     ON de.ExSName = d.SName AND de.ExPName = d.PNAme
GROUP BY d.SNAME, d.PNAME
ORDER BY d.SNAME, d.PNAME;
```

However, your method is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the `ExSName, ExPName` is unique in

Here is another way using `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT SName,
       PName,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN de.ExSName IS NULL THEN ( SoldCount )
             ELSE 0
           END)   AS SoldCount,
       Sum(Value) AS Value
FROM   #Details d
       LEFT JOIN (select distinct ExSName,ExPName from #DetailsException) de
              ON de.ExSName = d.SName
                 AND de.ExPName = d.PNAme
GROUP  BY SNAME,
          PNAME
ORDER  BY SNAME,
          PNAME
```

Check the performance by running the queries. You can create Non-clustered index on  `SName,PNAme` column to improve the performance

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_details_temp
  ON #Details (SNAME, PNAME)
  include (SoldCount, Value);
```

Added covering index (`SoldCount, Value`) to avoid Clustered/Heap lookup. Note, Index will be useful only if you are going to filter records from `#details` table. And for `#DetailsException` table creating the below index could be helpful

```
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_DetailsException_temp
  ON #DetailsException (ExSName, ExPName)
```